# Integrating a curve in python between two points

Tags: python, scipy

I need to integrate a curve I created using data points because I want to find the value in a particular region. So, I want to integrate it only between two points. scipy.trapz doesn't take endpoints. scipy.integrate doesn't let me do that because my x-axis is not as simple as linspace(a, b, n). Is there any way I could still integrate between just two points? The brute force way of defining an interval between those two points won't work because my function is created from interpolating over the range.

To be clearer, my function is the flux sed and my x-axis is the wavelength. In my integration, I will convert wavelength to frequency, but I'm not sure how to do the integration itself with the limits.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Integrate with respect to what?

Comment: The x axis (wavelength)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you have an array of some length, let's call it `y_array`, and you want to find the area given some endpoints relative to another array, let's call `x_array`. I'll use a simple function to show the integration from 0 to 1 of `x**2`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_array = np.linspace(0,2,201)
y_array = x_array**2

plt.plot(x_array, y_array)
plt.show()
```

[image: x squared array]

If you were to do this integral by hand from 0 to 1, you'd expect something close to 0.333...

We can use `np.trapz(...)` for this, but first we need to find the index in the `x_array` that we want to use, and the stepsize to feed Numpy's trapezoidal rule.

```
print(x_array[0], x_array[100])
# Gives 0.0, and 1.0
dx = (x_array[100]-x_array[0])/len(x_array[0:100])
# Gives the slices dx between these bounds
print(dx)
# Gives 0.01
```

Now we plug this in

```
area = np.trapz(y_array[0:100], dx = dx)
print(area)
# Gives 0.3234494... (~2% relative error)
```

Which gives the approximate area under the curve in those bounds. Of course this isn't the most accurate but I believe you could do something similar with SciPy's Simpson Rule.

I think this is what you were trying to do, and I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing. I used np.where and created filtered arrays and then used those to integrate.

Comment: I am glad to have helped! I ran into the same issues when doing my project. Feel free to accept my answer if you want ;)